# How to add SKShapeNode to random position until screen getting full

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skshapenode

I want to add `SKShapeNode` to random position, using Sprite Kit, until  the screen getting full.

How can I find the empty space in screen?

Comment: You should generate random position, and then check if there are no nodes there. You should provide more spefic question to get more specific answer. :)

Comment: How can i check the size of shape and the empty space?

Comment: What are you trying to do ? Maybe a puzzle game? Can you give an example of your idea?

Answer (score 0):

This is not an off the shelf kind of function in SK. Your only solution would be to create a hack to do what you want. One possible approach might be to create a very small node and place it in various positions on the screen, using a loop. For example (x,y position), 0,0 -> 4,0 -> 8,0 and so on...

You can use the `func intersectsNode(_ node: SKNode) -> Bool` to see if this node intersects any other node.

Another approach might be to use the same kind of logic but use `func containsPoint(_ p: CGPoint) -> Bool` instead.

Both approaches would be processor intensive so you should only run them sparingly.